# Trying to load a very long list to WPF DataGrid

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid, dataset

I have a very large xml file, 4,677 KB - basically around 26000 lines, each looking like:

```
<samples>
<sample id=1 field =test field1=test1 field2=test2 field3=""test3"" field4=""test4"" field5=""test5"" field6=""test6"" field7=""test7""  field8=""test8"" field9=""test9"" field10=""test10""   />
<sample id=""2"" field =""test"" field1=""test1"" field2=""test2"" field3=""test3"" field4=""test4"" field5=""test5"" field6=""test6"" field7=""test7""  field8=""test8"" field9=""test9"" field10=""test10""   />
<sample id=""3"" field =""test"" field1=""test1"" field2=""test2"" field3=""test3"" field4=""test4"" field5=""test5"" field6=""test6"" field7=""test7""  field8=""test8"" field9=""test9"" field10=""test10""   />
```

...

and I'm trying to load this into a WPF DataGrid using a DataSet/DataView. Sure enough, OutOfMemoryException was fired when trying to bind to this as so:

```
        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <HeaderedContentControl Header="Sample Data">
        <DataGrid
                x:Name="DataGrid"
                AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=GridData, Mode=OneWay}">
            </DataGrid>
        </HeaderedContentControl>
    </Grid>
```

I tried adding the VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" (although that's the default) and also VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling", but it didn't help.

I know this is tons of data for the control, I'm wondering what my options are.

Comment: Try to use XML Streaming instead of normal XML loading. Streaming might help you get rid of Memory Exception

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the **Width** and **Height** of the **DataGrid** to fix values. This is what fixed the problem in our case.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <HeaderedContentControl Header="Sample Data">
        <DataGrid
            x:Name="DataGrid"
            Width="600" Height="400"
            AutoGenerateColumns="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=GridData, Mode=OneWay}">
        </DataGrid>
    </HeaderedContentControl>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that 4,7Megs of data will give you an out of memory exception. Furthermore, as you already wrote, DataGrid works in virtualizing mode. Do you get the exception after setting the ItensSource?
Try loading the data without attaching it to the DataGrid. Then you know if the problem is the loading code. I would check the loading code for an infinite loop.

Comment: I didn't think so either.  I get the exception after binding the ItemsSource to the dataset.Tables[0].DefaultView - but after a very very long wait. The XDocument.Load returns quickly, the dataset.ReadXml returns fairly quickly, but when the control is trying to render those, there is a wait of around 7-10 min, nothing happens, and then the exception raises.

Comment: Any idea how to troubleshoot this further?

Comment: @user350213: If I work with DataGrid, I always make a ViewModel per item (a wrapper around each row-item). I never had a problem with this. One thing more: Have you activated grouping? If yes, this would be the problem because grouping eliminates the possibility to virtualize the items.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with HCL that this does not seem to be related to the rendering of these controls. My suggestion would be for you to have a view model with a separate data structure bound to the View. Then load the data structure from your xml file. This way you separate the tasks and you'll narrow down to the problem. Certainly the binding piece is not the culprit.

Comment: Thanks Gustavo. Actually I do have it in a MVVM structure, where GridData is property of the MainWindowViewModel returning a DataView. I put it directly in the view to eliminate doubts. Its true that I don't have a specific data structure for this - I kinda let the DataSet organize it for me

Comment: I would create my own lists for the structure and populate them by looping through the xml instead of using a DataSet. At least until the problem is discovered.